# How do you auto-activate plugins from child themes

Tags: plugins, functions, child-theme

(repost from [Theme Hybrid Community](http://themehybrid.com/community/topic/how-to-auto-activate-plugins-from-child-themes))

Let's assume a plugin or multiple-plugins are hosted on WordPress.org. Can you automatically activate plugins with the functions.php of a child theme? Is there any problem with doing such a thing?

What's the best way to add plugin functionality to a child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this function in your theme and use this hookfunction

```
wp_register_theme_activation_hook($code, $function) {
    $optionKey="theme_is_activated_" . $code;
    if(!get_option($optionKey)) {
        call_user_func($function);
        update_option($optionKey , 1);
    }
}
```

functions and examples:

```
<?php
/**
 * Provides activation/deactivation hook for wordpress theme.
 *
 * @author Krishna Kant Sharma (http://www.krishnakantsharma.com)
 *
 * Usage:
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * Include this file in your theme code.
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * function my_theme_activate() {
 *    // code to execute on theme activation
 * }
 * wp_register_theme_activation_hook('mytheme', 'my_theme_activate');
 *
 * function my_theme_deactivate() {
 *    // code to execute on theme deactivation
 * }
 * wp_register_theme_deactivation_hook('mytheme', 'my_theme_deactivate');
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * 
 * 
 */

/**
 *
 * @desc registers a theme activation hook
 * @param string $code : Code of the theme. This can be the base folder of your theme. Eg if your theme is in folder 'mytheme' then code will be 'mytheme'
 * @param callback $function : Function to call when theme gets activated.
 */
function wp_register_theme_activation_hook($code, $function) {
    $optionKey="theme_is_activated_" . $code;
    if(!get_option($optionKey)) {
        call_user_func($function);
        update_option($optionKey , 1);
    }
}

/**
 * @desc registers deactivation hook
 * @param string $code : Code of the theme. This must match the value you provided in wp_register_theme_activation_hook function as $code
 * @param callback $function : Function to call when theme gets deactivated.
 */
function wp_register_theme_deactivation_hook($code, $function) {
    // store function in code specific global
    $GLOBALS["wp_register_theme_deactivation_hook_function" . $code]=$function;

    // create a runtime function which will delete the option set while activation of this theme and will call deactivation function provided in $function
    $fn=create_function('$theme', ' call_user_func($GLOBALS["wp_register_theme_deactivation_hook_function' . $code . '"]); delete_option("theme_is_activated_' . $code. '");');

    // add above created function to switch_theme action hook. This hook gets called when admin changes the theme.
    // Due to wordpress core implementation this hook can only be received by currently active theme (which is going to be deactivated as admin has chosen another one.
    // Your theme can perceive this hook as a deactivation hook.
    add_action("switch_theme", $fn);
}
```

for more information see [this post](http://www.krishnakantsharma.com/2011/01/activationdeactivation-hook-for-wordpress-theme/)

Answer (score 0):

While this is quite possible technically I think this is poor workflow. Basically there are two cases here:

1. Theme entirely cannot function without specific plugin(s). I think it is unwanted case overall and if absolutely required it makes sense to port plugin's functionality into theme itself.
2. Theme makes use of plugins for advanced features. It is not hard to detect if plugin is running ([`is_plugin_active()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active), [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php), etc) and conditionally run code or notify that specific feature uses plugin and not natively available.