# How to add a plugin in WordPress theme directory?

Tags: plugins, themes

before I start the topic, I want you to know that I am aware of what I do and the risk and missing the updates and missing security and etc.

I want to put any plugin in my WordPress theme directory.
for example adding woocommerce plugin in `wp-content/themes/my-theme-directory` and I want the plugins directory totally clean of any other plugin.
the solution for Advance Custom Fields plugin is like this:

```
// Define path and URL to the ACF plugin.
define( 'MY_ACF_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/acf/' );
define( 'MY_ACF_URL', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/acf/' );

// Include the ACF plugin.
include_once( MY_ACF_PATH . 'acf.php' );

// Customize the url setting to fix incorrect asset URLs.
add_filter('acf/settings/url', 'my_acf_settings_url');
function my_acf_settings_url( $url ) {
    return MY_ACF_URL;
}

// (Optional) Hide the ACF admin menu item.
add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', 'my_acf_settings_show_admin');
function my_acf_settings_show_admin( $show_admin ) {
    return false;
}
```

I did the same for other plugins but I miss some styles and js files.
for example after transfering the wpDiscuz plugin to my-theme-directory/includes I put this code in functions.php but I missed styles at the front:

```
<?php
define( 'MY_WPDZ_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/wpdiscuz/' );
define( 'MY_WPDZ_URL', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/wpdiscuz/' );
include_once( MY_WPDZ_PATH . 'class.WpdiscuzCore.php' );
?>
```

what should I do? what is the solution?

Comment: `MY_ACF_PATH` and `MY_ACF_URL` are unique and specific to ACF, this looks like you're asking how to implement a solution, not how to solve your problem. You could just as easily have your theme install the plugins automatically or prompt the user that they're necessary. Right now a user with WooCommerce already installed who activates your theme if you did this would break their site

Comment: ACF is specifically designed to be bundled with themes. Most plugins are not.

Comment: @TomJNowell
1) if someone see woocommerce in the admin menu, why would they install the woocommerce again?
2) who says there will be a plugin access when I totally hide it?
3) this is just for the websites which I'll give to my customers.
if you can solve the problem, then I'm waiting for the answer.

Comment: because they were told to, automation did it, or another plugin did it automatically, or WooCommerce itself did it (some plugins have built in updaters to forcing security updates) there's lots of reasons someone might do so. I understand you have a problem this is going to solve for you, but this is not the only solution, or the best one. It's possible you have genuine reasons for doing it this way, but you have not shared any, and to my knowledge none exist that don't have superior alternatives. Perhaps your themes have an update mechanism that you're trying to force into doing double duty?

Comment: @TomJNowell at the first line of the topic I clearly mentioned this:
`before I start the topic, I want you to know that I am aware of what I do and the risk and missing the updates and missing security and etc. `
didn't I?
so if you can not give any solution in this case, please do not reply any more.

Comment: I would advise a calmer demeanour. If you do not explain why then it is natural that people will ask. Context will both avoid people asking, and enhance the answers you get. For example, if you are indeed trying to simplify updating then some solutions will not work for you. Likewise if you want this because you are trying to sell the theme in question that also changes the answer. It's even possible you're doing this to comply with classic WP.com VIP, for which there is a completely different answer. This isn't a discussion forum, you should provide the context for why, it is important

Comment: dear @TomJNowell , It is for a local space which there is no internet and this is not for sell. so missing updates is not important and the security will be handled by local network.
also every time you go to the dashboard, WordPress checks that which plugins are activated or not and it makes a low performance (even for 0.001 ms) and it is needed the plugins must be activated directly (not via switch).
these are the reasons.

Comment: if that's the case, then why not turn off update checking with a filter and force the plugins on via another filter? Or use the `mu-plugins` folder? This Q has everything needed to disable updates and HTTP requests from WP https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102554/prevent-disable-automatic-update-check and this auto-activates plugins from a theme https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10999/how-do-you-auto-activate-plugins-from-child-themes

Comment: @TomJNowell , Now the problem is solved by your helping hands.
I did not know about `mu-plugins directory`
I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved
Thanks to @TomJNowell
Solution:

1. make a directory under the `wp-content` directory and name it `mu-plugins`
2. then move your plugin directory (for example woocommerce) in `wp-content/mu-plugins`
3. after that you have to call it for your WordPress by crating a file and name it `load.php`
4. introduce the plugin bin `load.php` for example:

`<?php require WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR.'/woocommerce/woocommerce.php';`

Done :)

Comment: You shouldn't have to require files from mu-plugins I don't think? They should get loaded automatically before any other plugins.

Comment: But I'm not really sure woocommerce belongs in mu-plugins anyway.

Comment: @Rup mu-plugins will only load PHP files directly in the mu-plugins/ directory. If you put a folder in there nothing will load. You need a PHP file that includes the main file from the plugin folder.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks, didn't know that, I've only used it for single file plugins.